# Functional equation link two Dirichlet series

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, half-integral-weight

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1}a(n)n^{(k-1/2)/2}e(nz)\in S_{k+1/2}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi)$ be a cuspidal Hecke eigenform. Let 
$$M(s)=\sum_{p\ge 2, \text{prime}}\frac{|a(p)|^2}{p^s}$$ and
$$R_f(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{|a(n)|^2}{n^s}$$
Is there a functional equation link the two series ?

Comment: The second is approximately the Rankin-Selberg convolution of the standard $L$-function attached to $f$ with itself. It has a functional equation. The first displayed expression is a fragment of the logarithm of the second, and I'd wager that it has a natural boundary...

Comment: @paulgarrett, Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Dear @paulgarrett, Could you please explain to me what you mean by  "The first displayed expression is a fragment of the logarithm of the second,"

Comment: Hecke eigenform means $R_f(s)$ has an Euler product $R_f(s)= \prod_p 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a(p^k)^2 p^{-sk}$, so that  $\log R_f(s) = \mathcal{O}(1) + \sum_p a(p)^2 p^{-s}+ a(p^2)^2 p^{-2s}$ for $Re(s) > k+1/2+\epsilon$ (or something like that)

Comment: @paulgarrett , @ user1952009,  I think that you are overlooked that f is a modular form of half-integral weight  ....!!!

Comment: @user1952009, We don't really have an Euler product in the half-integral weight case !!!

Comment: Ah, indeed, I did overlook the half-integral aspect... but, still, your $R_f$ could be obtained by integrating $|f|^2$ against suitable $E_s$ as usual. And I'd still be very surprised if just taking prime-index components didn't have a natural boundary.

Comment: reading [Shimura, on modular forms of half integral weight](http://cecas.clemson.edu/~janoski/reu/2009/modularForms/73_shimu.pdf) , theorem 1.9 p.13 it says $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(tn) n^{-s}$ has an Euler product whenever $t $ is square-free and $> 1$

Comment: @user1952009, That's not what I am looking for :-)  I am interested to a functional equation, look like $M(s)=\Delta(s)R_f(s)$

Comment: you mean $M(s) \approx \log R_f(s)$, and what I wrote should give $\sum_p |a(tp)|^2 p^{-s} \approx \log(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a(tn)|^2 n^{-s})$